# Pandas filtering data frame by date, which is in different format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, dataframe

So I load a csv file into a pandas dataframe without any problems.

`df = pd.read_csv(filename,na_values=[""])`

There is a column in the csv called date_GMT with the date in the format Jun 29 2017 - 2:00pm. The problem is it treats this value as a string when I make comparisons to filter out examples. How do I make treat it as a date.

```
df=df[(df['date_GMT'] < datetime.date(year=2017,month=8,day=25))]
```

I attempted this which does not work because it cannot compare strings and dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `datetime` before your comparison:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Jun 29 2017 - 2:00pm', 'Sep 2 2018 - 4:00pm',
                           'Jan 15 2017 - 6:00am', 'Mar 29 2018 - 11:00pm']})

df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])

print(df.loc[df['col'] < '2017-08-25'])

                  col
0 2017-06-29 14:00:00
2 2017-01-15 06:00:00
```

Better still, you can specify `datetime` columns when you read your file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=['date_GMT'])
```